# dynamic_sidebar not rendering sidebar

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I have the following code

```
// in functions.php
register_sidebar(array(
    'before_widget' => '<section>',
    'after_widget' => '</section>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));

// in sidebar.php
if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar()) : ?>
    // static sidebar here ..
```

I find that the static sidebar is what renders even if I add widgets in the dashboard. I'm not sure if WP3.2 caused it as I never tried using dynamic sidebar before updating

Answer (score 6):

You should add the `name` and `id` parameters to your `register_sidebar()` argument array:

```
'name'=>'Sidebar Name',
'id'=>'sidebar-slug',
```

Like such:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=>'Sidebar Name',
    'id'=>'sidebar-slug',
    'before_widget' => '<section>',
    'after_widget' => '</section>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

Then call the `id` of the Sidebar in your `dynamic_sidebar()` call:

```
if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-slug' ) ) {

}
```

By the way: you don't need to include a `function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) )` conditional; this functionality has been in WordPress since version 2.8.